# Angular material combine input filter and sorted column

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How can I combine filtering by input and sorted column using material design table? Is it possible if sorting columns and filtering input use the same method connect() ?

I get examples from https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

I don't know how to do it because both filter and sort use the same method and in these examples was shown that method connect has to have diffrent implementations for sorting and filtering.

Example with input filtering:

```js
import {Component, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';

@Component({
  selector: 'table-filtering-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-filtering-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-filtering-example.html',
})
export class TableFilteringExample {
  displayedColumns = ['userId', 'userName', 'progress', 'color'];
  exampleDatabase = new ExampleDatabase();
  dataSource: ExampleDataSource | null;

  @ViewChild('filter') filter: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new ExampleDataSource(this.exampleDatabase);
    Observable.fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, 'keyup')
        .debounceTime(150)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(() => {
          if (!this.dataSource) { return; }
          this.dataSource.filter = this.filter.nativeElement.value;
        });
  }
}

/** Constants used to fill up our data base. */
const COLORS = ['maroon', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'olive', 'green', 'purple',
  'fuchsia', 'lime', 'teal', 'aqua', 'blue', 'navy', 'black', 'gray'];
const NAMES = ['Maia', 'Asher', 'Olivia', 'Atticus', 'Amelia', 'Jack',
  'Charlotte', 'Theodore', 'Isla', 'Oliver', 'Isabella', 'Jasper',
  'Cora', 'Levi', 'Violet', 'Arthur', 'Mia', 'Thomas', 'Elizabeth'];

export interface UserData {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  progress: string;
  color: string;
}

/** An example database that the data source uses to retrieve data for the table. */
export class ExampleDatabase {
  /** Stream that emits whenever the data has been modified. */
  dataChange: BehaviorSubject<UserData[]> = new BehaviorSubject<UserData[]>([]);
  get data(): UserData[] { return this.dataChange.value; }

  constructor() {
    // Fill up the database with 100 users.
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) { this.addUser(); }
  }

  /** Adds a new user to the database. */
  addUser() {
    const copiedData = this.data.slice();
    copiedData.push(this.createNewUser());
    this.dataChange.next(copiedData);
  }

  /** Builds and returns a new User. */
  private createNewUser() {
    const name =
        NAMES[Math.round(Math.random() * (NAMES.length - 1))] + ' ' +
        NAMES[Math.round(Math.random() * (NAMES.length - 1))].charAt(0) + '.';

    return {
      id: (this.data.length + 1).toString(),
      name: name,
      progress: Math.round(Math.random() * 100).toString(),
      color: COLORS[Math.round(Math.random() * (COLORS.length - 1))]
    };
  }
}

/**
 * Data source to provide what data should be rendered in the table. Note that the data source
 * can retrieve its data in any way. In this case, the data source is provided a reference
 * to a common data base, ExampleDatabase. It is not the data source's responsibility to manage
 * the underlying data. Instead, it only needs to take the data and send the table exactly what
 * should be rendered.
 */
export class ExampleDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  _filterChange = new BehaviorSubject('');
  get filter(): string { return this._filterChange.value; }
  set filter(filter: string) { this._filterChange.next(filter); }

  constructor(private _exampleDatabase: ExampleDatabase) {
    super();
  }

  /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
  connect(): Observable<UserData[]> {
    const displayDataChanges = [
      this._exampleDatabase.dataChange,
      this._filterChange,
    ];

    return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
      return this._exampleDatabase.data.slice().filter((item: UserData) => {
        let searchStr = (item.name + item.color).toLowerCase();
        return searchStr.indexOf(this.filter.toLowerCase()) != -1;
      });
    });
  }

  disconnect() {}
}
```

Sorted column example:

```js
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk';
import {MdSort} from '@angular/material';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'table-sorting-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-sorting-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-sorting-example.html',
})
export class TableSortingExample {
  displayedColumns = ['userId', 'userName', 'progress', 'color'];
  exampleDatabase = new ExampleDatabase();
  dataSource: ExampleDataSource | null;

  @ViewChild(MdSort) sort: MdSort;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new ExampleDataSource(this.exampleDatabase, this.sort);
  }
}

/** Constants used to fill up our data base. */
const COLORS = ['maroon', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'olive', 'green', 'purple',
  'fuchsia', 'lime', 'teal', 'aqua', 'blue', 'navy', 'black', 'gray'];
const NAMES = ['Maia', 'Asher', 'Olivia', 'Atticus', 'Amelia', 'Jack',
  'Charlotte', 'Theodore', 'Isla', 'Oliver', 'Isabella', 'Jasper',
  'Cora', 'Levi', 'Violet', 'Arthur', 'Mia', 'Thomas', 'Elizabeth'];

export interface UserData {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  progress: string;
  color: string;
}

/** An example database that the data source uses to retrieve data for the table. */
export class ExampleDatabase {
  /** Stream that emits whenever the data has been modified. */
  dataChange: BehaviorSubject<UserData[]> = new BehaviorSubject<UserData[]>([]);
  get data(): UserData[] { return this.dataChange.value; }

  constructor() {
    // Fill up the database with 100 users.
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) { this.addUser(); }
  }

  /** Adds a new user to the database. */
  addUser() {
    const copiedData = this.data.slice();
    copiedData.push(this.createNewUser());
    this.dataChange.next(copiedData);
  }

  /** Builds and returns a new User. */
  private createNewUser() {
    const name =
        NAMES[Math.round(Math.random() * (NAMES.length - 1))] + ' ' +
        NAMES[Math.round(Math.random() * (NAMES.length - 1))].charAt(0) + '.';

    return {
      id: (this.data.length + 1).toString(),
      name: name,
      progress: Math.round(Math.random() * 100).toString(),
      color: COLORS[Math.round(Math.random() * (COLORS.length - 1))]
    };
  }
}

/**
 * Data source to provide what data should be rendered in the table. Note that the data source
 * can retrieve its data in any way. In this case, the data source is provided a reference
 * to a common data base, ExampleDatabase. It is not the data source's responsibility to manage
 * the underlying data. Instead, it only needs to take the data and send the table exactly what
 * should be rendered.
 */
export class ExampleDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  constructor(private _exampleDatabase: ExampleDatabase, private _sort: MdSort) {
    super();
  }

  /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
  connect(): Observable<UserData[]> {
    const displayDataChanges = [
      this._exampleDatabase.dataChange,
      this._sort.mdSortChange,
    ];

    return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
      return this.getSortedData();
    });
  }

  disconnect() {}

  /** Returns a sorted copy of the database data. */
  getSortedData(): UserData[] {
    const data = this._exampleDatabase.data.slice();
    if (!this._sort.active || this._sort.direction == '') { return data; }

    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      let propertyA: number|string = '';
      let propertyB: number|string = '';

      switch (this._sort.active) {
        case 'userId': [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.id, b.id]; break;
        case 'userName': [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.name, b.name]; break;
        case 'progress': [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.progress, b.progress]; break;
        case 'color': [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.color, b.color]; break;
      }

      let valueA = isNaN(+propertyA) ? propertyA : +propertyA;
      let valueB = isNaN(+propertyB) ? propertyB : +propertyB;

      return (valueA < valueB ? -1 : 1) * (this._sort.direction == 'asc' ? 1 : -1);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An example has been added [to the docs](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/material-examples/table-overview) and will show up after the next release.

Relevant connect method:

```
/** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
connect(): Observable<UserData[]> {
  // Listen for any changes in the base data, sorting, filtering, or pagination
  const displayDataChanges = [
    this._exampleDatabase.dataChange,
    this._sort.mdSortChange,
    this._filterChange,
    this._paginator.page,
  ];

  return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
    // Filter data
    this.filteredData = this._exampleDatabase.data.slice().filter((item: UserData) => {
      let searchStr = (item.name + item.color).toLowerCase();
      return searchStr.indexOf(this.filter.toLowerCase()) != -1;
    });

    // Sort filtered data
    const sortedData = this.sortData(this.filteredData.slice());

    // Grab the page's slice of the filtered sorted data.
    const startIndex = this._paginator.pageIndex * this._paginator.pageSize;
    this.renderedData = sortedData.splice(startIndex, this._paginator.pageSize);
    return this.renderedData;
  });
}
```